# Camera Calibration Matrix how to?

Tags: language-agnostic, math, matrix, camera, camera-calibration

With [this](http://graphics.cs.msu.ru/ru/science/research/calibration/cpp) toolbox I was performing calibration of my camera.

However the toolbox outputs results in matrix form, and being a noob I don't really understand mathy stuff.

The matrix is in the following form.

[image]

Where R is a rotation matrix, T is a translation vector.

And these are the results I got from the toolbox. It outputs values in pixels.

```
-0.980755   -0.136184  -0.139905  217.653207
0.148552    -0.055504  -0.987346  995.948880
0.126695    -0.989128  0.074666  371.963957
0.000000    0.000000  0.000000  1.000000
```

Using this data can I know how much my camera is rotated and distance of it from the calibration object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distance part is easy.  The translation from the origin is given by the first three numbers in the rightmost column.  This represents the translation in the x, y, and z directions respectively.  In your example, the camera's position p = (p<sub>x</sub>, p<sub>y</sub>, p<sub>z</sub>) = (217.653207, 995.948880, 371.963957).  You can take the Euclidean distance between the camera's location and the location of the calibration object (c<sub>x</sub>, c<sub>y</sub>, c<sub>z</sub>). That is it would just be sqrt( (p<sub>x</sub>-c<sub>x</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (p<sub>y</sub>-c<sub>y</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (p<sub>z</sub>-c<sub>z</sub>)<sup>2</sup> )

The more difficult part regards the rotation which is captured in the upper left 3x3 elements of the matrix.  Without knowing exactly how they arrived at this, you're somewhat out of luck. That is, it's not easy to convert that back to [Euler Angles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles), if that's what you want.  However, you can transform those elements into a [Quaternion Rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_rotation) which will give you the unique unit vector and angle to rotate the camera to that orientation. The specifics of the computation are provided [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_rotation#Conversion_to_and_from_the_matrix_representation).  Once you have the Quaternion rotation, you can easily apply it to the vectors n = (0, 0, 1), up = (0, 1, 0) and right = (1, 0, 0) to get the normal (direction the camera is pointed), up and right vectors.  The right vector is only useful if you are interested in slewing the camera left or right from its current position.

Comment: What is considered the origin is it the camera lens or the calibration paper sheet center? Translation, I now understand but I still don't know How do I get cx, cy and cz or distance from the camera to the calibration object?

Comment: It may be that the software considers the calibration object to be at the origin.  In that case cx=cy=cz=0.  If that's not the case, you're going to have to consult the toolbox documentation.

Comment: Looking a little more completely at the website you referenced, it seems the documentation is somewhat sparse.  So, you have a couple other options.  The first is to try to figure it out from the source code provided; the other is attempt to contact the authors and see what information they can provide you.

Comment: thanks I'll do that, are you aware of any other camera calibration softwares.

Comment: @Kevin Boyd:  There'some additional references at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_resectioning.  Also, it occurs to me that you could directly apply the R values in the matrix to the canonical vectors n, up, and right rather than converting to Quaternion Rotations.  I've been on a Quaternion kick lately and so consider them essential for rotations.  But, that's not the case here.

Comment: @Andand: Is the top left of the grid is 0,0,0 and I have the R (3x3 rotation matrix)
r  (3x1 rotation vector )
T (translation vector)
is it possible for me to compute the position and rotation of the cam.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the code uses the '[standard](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/bouguetj/calib_doc/index.html)' formation - then you will find more details in the [opencv library docs](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html) or their book.

Comment: In this context Dr  Jean-Yves Bouguet's, which is IIRC based on http://www.amazon.com/Multiple-View-Geometry-Computer-Vision/dp/0521540518/ref=wl_it_dp_o?ie=UTF8&coliid=I2HGS590RAY8I9&colid=37VYKHXCSPCID